# couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I have tried multiple answers on stackoverflow and non seem to work, but here is the question anyways.

Im trying to use `active-admin` with my `Rails 5` application.

In my gem file I have:

```
gem 'activeadmin', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

In my application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

In my application.scss I have:

```
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "jquery-ui/datepicker";
```

Despite following all the instructions as stated I'm getting an error:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript
```

and the error seems to be happening here:

```
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

**EDIT**

I have a redirect in the `action_controller.rb`

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    home_mypath_path
  end
```

Which I think is interfering with the login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just require the old jquery-ui-rails version:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre4'
```

put it before activeadmin. this works for rails 5.

from the [jquery-ui-rails github page](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails):

> Warning: Due to directory structure changes between jQuery UI 1.10,
>   1.11, and 1.12, if you use version is lower than 6.0, you will have to use a different naming for the files to require, please check
>   following links for more information: [for 5.0 users](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails/blob/v5.0.5/README.md), [for 4.2 users](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails/blob/v4.2.1/README.md).

Comment: This solution takes me past the error, but now it redirects me back to the home page

Comment: @GurmukhSingh dude you could easily accept my answer. thanks

Answer (score 6):

The newest version of jquery-ui has restructured the library.

Try the following:

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

And

```
@import "jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker";
```

Comment: i still get an error `File to import not found or unreadable: jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker`

Comment: this is the right answer if you want to use jquery-rails with version 6.0 above,

Comment: For Rails 5 users, do not change the application.scss file. I just needed to add /widgets/ to my application.js file, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

helped me as well

```
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```